# Reading from TResourceStream

Tags: delphi

I am trying to read some gif and bitmaps from resource file, I am using resource hacker to include the images into project.res file but the code I am using doesn't seem to return the right count of images.

Below is what I am trying to do

```
Stream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance,'EMOTES','BIN');
GetMem(Buffer,40000);
Stream.Read(StreamCount,4);
For I := 0 To StreamCount - 1 Do Begin
  Stream.Read(StreamSize,4);
  Stream.Read(Buffer^,StreamSize);
  ImageStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  ImageStream.Write(Buffer^,StreamSize);
  ImageStreamList.Add(ImageStream);
  ImageStream.Free;
End;
FreeMem(Buffer);
Stream.Free;
```

Comment: Well, what exactly is the problem? What is the input, what is the expected output, and what is the actual output? FWIW if you want to include resources then you don't need to use a GUI program the resource hacker. Modern versions of the Delphi IDE compile resources for you, with older versions use brcc32.

Comment: I added a gif to the .res file with "BIN" as resource type and "EMOTES" as resource name, so i expect streamcount as 1 but the streamcount value is some random number which at end causes access violation error. I am using Delphi 7

Comment: What is stream count? Why do you expect the first 4 bytes of a gif file to be $00000001? Surely you'll get the GIF header. What's special about `40000`?

Comment: the 40000 is maximum file size of the image, so the buffer is freed upto 40kb for the image stream, and about the first 4 bytes to be streamcount, i read the code somewhere so i am not sure why the first 4 bytes be the streamcount. is there any other way to return the count?

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be trying to load a GIF file from a resource. Do it like this:

```
Stream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'EMOTES', 'BIN');
try
  image.LoadFromStream(Stream);
finally
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

where `image` is an instantiated object of type `TGIFImage`.

I really cannot work out what your code is trying to do. Perhaps you have multiple images. In which case create one resource for each image, each resource having a different name. Note that I don't mean one .res file per image. You can put all your images into a single .rc file, each resource with a different name. Then compile that .rc file to a .res file and link to your application.